# IListSource and ToString() with DataSource

Tags: c#, datasource, tostring

First I have a Listbox and set the DataSource to a MyObjectCollection

MyObjectCollection implements the Interface IListSource wich contains MyObject's

MyObject has the method

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "test";
}
```

The Listbox now displays "test" for each element in the MyObjectCollection.

But if I apply the IListSource interface to MyObject, too. The Listbox shows an empty string. How to fix that in the "MyObject" class. 
A workaround is to fix it in the Listbox Format event, but than every GUI element has to implement this workaround :/

Comment: BTW - is this winform, wpf, or asp.net? I can't reproduce in winform...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, things should **either** be lists, *or* should be an entity for binding. If it is a list (`IList` or `IListSource`) then much of the data-binding API will assume you actually want (for simple-binding scenarios, i.e. one row) the *first* item from the sublist.

I would simply change it so that `MyObject` **doesn't** implement `IListSource`, but *encapsulates* it, perhaps exposing it via a `Items` property. You could also look at whether a custom `TypeConverter` would work (I'll investigate...)

Comment: To encapsulate it, is the best way for me. Maybe it was too easy ;)
Now i bind MyObject.ListProperty insteat of MyObject an everything works well.